# Error "import cycle not allowed" in go-swagger auto generated code

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am facing error "import cycle not allowed" in go-swagger auto-generated file, below is the code . I have also read other answers related to this problem but no success . If any other information is required please comment.

Thanks in advance

**items_swagger.yaml**

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: Item list swagger for performing various op like create , delete , update.
  title: ItemList
  version: 1.0.0
consumes:
- application/json
produces:
- application/json
schemes:
- http
paths:
    /createItem:
      post:
        tags:
          - createItem
        operationId: createOne
        parameters:
          - name: body
            in: body
            schema:
              $ref: '#/definitions/item'
        responses:
          200:
            description: Created
            schema:
              $ref: '#/definitions/item'
          default:
            description:
              error
            schema:
              $ref: "#/definitions/error"

    /updateItem:
      put:
        tags:
          - updateItem
        operationId: updateone
        parameters:
          - name: body
            in: body
            schema:
              $ref: "#/definitions/item"
        responses:
          200:
            description: OK
            schema:
              $ref: "#/definitions/item"
          default:
            description: error
            schema:
              $ref: "#/definitions/error"

    /deleteItems:
      delete:
        tags:
          - deleteItem
        operationId:  purgeItems
        responses:
          204:
            description: Deleted
          default:
            description:  error
            schema:
              $ref: "#/definitions/error"

definitions:
  item:
    type: object
    required:
      - id
      - itemName
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
        readOnly: false
      itemName:
        type: string
        format: string
        readOnly: false

  error:
    type: object
    required:
      - message
      - code
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format:  int
      message:
        type: string
```

**When I am generating it's model it is generating successfully .**

```
beast@beast-VirtualBox:~/Documents/WorkSpace_Go/ItemsSwagger/src$ swagger generate server -A ItemsSwagger -f ../swagger/items-swagger.yml -t generate
2020/04/14 20:25:19 validating spec /home/beast/Documents/WorkSpace_Go/ItemsSwagger/swagger/items-swagger.yml
2020/04/14 20:25:21 preprocessing spec with option:  minimal flattening
2020/04/14 20:25:21 building a plan for generation
2020/04/14 20:25:21 generation target generate
2020/04/14 20:25:21 planning definitions
2020/04/14 20:25:21 planning operations
2020/04/14 20:25:21 grouping operations into packages
2020/04/14 20:25:21 planning meta data and facades
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 2 models
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 1 templates for model error
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field error
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field models
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "error.go" in "generate/models" as definition
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:model
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 1 templates for model item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field models
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "item.go" in "generate/models" as definition
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:model
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 3 operation groups (tags)
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 1 operations for create_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 4 templates for operation ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field createOne
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field create_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "create_one_parameters.go" in "generate/restapi/operations/create_item" as parameters
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverParameter
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field createOne
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field create_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "create_one_urlbuilder.go" in "generate/restapi/operations/create_item" as urlbuilder
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverUrlbuilder
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field createOne
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field create_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "create_one_responses.go" in "generate/restapi/operations/create_item" as responses
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverResponses
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field createOne
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field create_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "create_one.go" in "generate/restapi/operations/create_item" as handler
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverOperation
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 0 templates for operation group ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 1 operations for delete_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 4 templates for operation ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field purgeItems
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field delete_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "purge_items_parameters.go" in "generate/restapi/operations/delete_item" as parameters
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverParameter
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field purgeItems
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field delete_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "purge_items_urlbuilder.go" in "generate/restapi/operations/delete_item" as urlbuilder
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverUrlbuilder
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field purgeItems
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field delete_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "purge_items_responses.go" in "generate/restapi/operations/delete_item" as responses
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverResponses
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field purgeItems
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field delete_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "purge_items.go" in "generate/restapi/operations/delete_item" as handler
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverOperation
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 0 templates for operation group ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 1 operations for update_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 4 templates for operation ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field updateone
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field update_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "updateone_parameters.go" in "generate/restapi/operations/update_item" as parameters
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverParameter
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field updateone
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field update_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "updateone_urlbuilder.go" in "generate/restapi/operations/update_item" as urlbuilder
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverUrlbuilder
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field updateone
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field update_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "updateone_responses.go" in "generate/restapi/operations/update_item" as responses
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverResponses
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field updateone
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field update_item
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "updateone.go" in "generate/restapi/operations/update_item" as handler
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverOperation
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 0 templates for operation group ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering support
2020/04/14 20:25:21 rendering 6 templates for application ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field operations
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field operations
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "main.go" in "generate/cmd/items-swagger-server" as main
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverMain
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field operations
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "embedded_spec.go" in "generate/restapi" as embedded_spec
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:swaggerJsonEmbed
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field operations
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "server.go" in "generate/restapi" as server
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverServer
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field operations
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "items_swagger_api.go" in "generate/restapi/operations" as builder
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverBuilder
2020/04/14 20:25:21 name field ItemsSwagger
2020/04/14 20:25:21 package field operations
2020/04/14 20:25:21 creating generated file "doc.go" in "generate/restapi" as doc
2020/04/14 20:25:21 executed template asset:serverDoc
2020/04/14 20:25:21 Generation completed!

For this generation to compile you need to have some packages in your GOPATH:

        * github.com/go-openapi/runtime
        * github.com/jessevdk/go-flags

You can get these now with: go get -u -f generate/...
```

> Error is occurring here , when I am trying to start the server.

```
beast@beast-VirtualBox:~/Documents/WorkSpace_Go/ItemsSwagger/src$ go run generate/cmd/items-swagger-server/main.go 
import cycle not allowed
package main
        imports generate/restapi
        imports context
        imports errors
        imports internal/reflectlite
        imports runtime
        imports internal/cpu
        imports runtime
beast@beast-VirtualBox:~/Documents/WorkSpace_Go/ItemsSwagger/src$
```

***go env* output**

```
beast@beast-VirtualBox:~/Documents/WorkSpace_Go/ItemsSwagger/src$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/beast/Documents/WorkSpace_Go/ItemsSwagger/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/beast/Documents/WorkSpace_Go/ItemsSwagger/"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
```

Edit 1 : Thank you Volker I am able to resolve "import cyclic error" by re-installing go , there was a conflict which caused by go_1.6 and go_1.9 version.

I ran "go run" command again but no success .

```
beast@beast-VirtualBox:~/Documents/WorkSpace_Go/ItemsSwagger/src$ go run generate/cmd/items-swagger-server/main.go 
# github.com/go-openapi/validate
github.com/go-openapi/validate/spec.go:46:16: undefined: loads.Document
github.com/go-openapi/validate/spec.go:57:16: undefined: loads.Document
github.com/go-openapi/validate/spec.go:59:16: undefined: loads.Document
github.com/go-openapi/validate/spec.go:75:10: undefined: loads.Document
github.com/go-openapi/validate/spec.go:78:21: undefined: loads.Document
# github.com/go-openapi/runtime/middleware/untyped
github.com/go-openapi/runtime/middleware/untyped/api.go:33:19: undefined: loads.Document
github.com/go-openapi/runtime/middleware/untyped/api.go:54:19: undefined: loads.Document
beast@beast-VirtualBox:~/Documents/WorkSpace_Go/ItemsSwagger/src$
```

I searched regarding the error only helpful link I found [here](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/issues/824).
I also tried generating swagger files fresh by deleting old one's .

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: You Go installation seems to be corrupt as the import cycle is in the stdlib. Start a fresh.

Comment: Please , elaborate how to start fresh , where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Delete Go, reinstall.

Comment: @Volker I have updated question , any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Volker suggested in comment ," import cycle not allowed " was resolved by doing the clean installation again . The problem was caused by multiple "Go" installation of versions  1.6 and 1.14 . Doing reinstallation of version 1.14 fixed it.

Second , problem which I faced regarding "loads.Document undefined " got fixed by  firing the command "swagger generate server -A ItemsSwagger -f ../swagger/items-swagger.yml" where dependencies are getting stored , so I think there was a dependency problem related to path, "Go" wasn't able to find it.

***For folks who are new to go-swagger , please refer below links:***

https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger

https://goswagger.io/tutorial/todo-list.html

https://www.ribice.ba/swagger-golang/

For re-installing "Go":

https://askubuntu.com/questions/742078/uninstalling-go-golang